# Como se mantienen las sesiones abiertas al cerrar el navegador?

Tags: session, cookies, sesiones

Me estaba planteando como hacen ciertas webs para mantener la sesión abierta indefinidamente. Por ejemplo, si tengo mi sesión abierta en google, cuando cierro y abro el navegador mi sesión sigue iniciada. Tengo entendido que los datos de la sesión se guardan en una cookie, y que las cookies se borran al cerrar el navegador. ¿Entonces como hacen para mantener la sesión abierta?

Comment: Hay dos suposiciones, una tras otra, que no son completamente ciertas y no se cumplen para todos los casos. No se guarda sólo en una cookie, siempre; no se borran al cerrar el navegador, siempre. Depende. Revisa esas afirmaciones y vas a encontrar la respuesta

Comment: Bienvenido, revisar [ask], saludos.